# Ransome Virus - Device Administrator deactivation impossible

Tags: android-device-manager

I am inside of the device administrator settings of my andorid phone while being in safe mode.
While I was able to delete one part of the ransome virus which was called "adult video", the second "adult video" stuck on my phone. Can't delete it.

I figured out that I need to deactivate the administrator rights from the device administration settings.

**Whenever I try to deactive the app within the device administration settings in safe mode, the app pops up and prevents me wiht a full screen thing**

The phone is not rooted. What can I do? Several anti virus programs failed also

Answer (score 2):

Clear the data of that app.
And try to remove that app from device administrator.

If it fail's then backup all important data and restore the device.
This will uninstall that app.